# Create grouped bar graph from dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Sample DataFrame

```
                 continent  avg_count_country  avg_age
Male        0      Asia                 55        5
            1    Africa                 65       10
            2    Europe                 75        8
Female      0      Asia                 50        7
            1    Africa                 60       12
            2    Europe                 70        0
Transgender 0      Asia                 30        6
            1    Africa                 40       11
            2    America                80       10
```

For the grouped bar graph:

X axis will have  `Male` , `Female` , `Transgender`

Y axis will have total counts

3 bars in each `Male` , `Female` and `Transgender`

Male and Female will have 3 bars grouped - `Asia` , `Africa` , `Europe`

Transgender will have 3 bars grouped  -- `Asia` , `Africa` , `America`

4 unique colors or legends [Asia , Africa ,Europe  , America]

I can do it manually like plotting every bar

```
bars1 = //manually giving values
bars2 = //manually giving values
......bars3, bars4

plt.bar(r1, bars1, color='#7f6d5f', width=barWidth, edgecolor='white', label='var1') 
and plotting each bar like this
```

But want to do it in more optimized way or dynamic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape your dataframe and use pandas plot:

```
df_out = df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)\
           .set_index(['continent'], append=True)['avg_count_country']\
           .unstack()

df_out.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]